# Recommended structure for multi Products and Customers

Tags: azure-devops

Let's say our company have 3 customers.

And we are developing 3 different products.

Products are built to allow customization for each customers.
Our repositories structure is thus as follow: For each products, we have a single Product-Core repository, and one Product-Customer repository for each customers.

Let's say these customers have bought these products:

-Cust1:

- Product1
- Product2
- Product3

-Cust2:

- Product1
- Product2

-Cust3:

- Product1
- Product3

We would like each customer's stakeholder to log into VSTS and see his backlog items for the products he bought.
It is extremely important that each customers don't see other customers items.
Developers must be able to see all workitems for all Products and all Customers.

Also, as stated before, each product has a Core repository and a Customer specific repository. 
So we may have to commit in both repositories when developing for a customer workitem.

What is the recommended structure to use in VSTS for this scenario, regarding Project / Teams / Security / etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the three products into three VSTS projects, and add customers as teams for different products/projects.

```
Projects        teams
---------------------------------
Product1    cust1, cust2, cust3
Product2    cust1, cust2
Product3    cust1, cust3
```

For different teams, you add different members and set certain permissions.

And set areas permissions so that teams only view theirs own work items. Such as in the work of product2 https://account.visualstudio.com/Product2/_admin/_work -> click Areas Tab -> set security for cust1 -> add users of cust2 -> set **View permissions for this node** and **View work items in this node** to Deny -> set users of cust1 to deny **View permissions for this node** and **View work items in this node** for cust2 Area too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that means a Stakeholder can't see all his work items from all his products consolidated in a single query/dashboard. He would have to switch between projects. Correct ?

Comment: No, Stakeholders can check or query WIT across projects.

Comment: Cool, I thought we couldn't, but seems supported: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/using-queries#across-projects

Comment: You can mark it as answer since it help you solve the problem :)

Comment: We are testing it :)